# How to track event of row selection in table in iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics

How to track events using Google Analytics? I can track the screen names but I can't track the events. I have code like this:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker trackEventWithCategory:@"UIAction"
                                                 withAction:@"buttonPress"
                                                  withLabel:@"Next button to second page"
                                                  withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

But what are the category, action, label and value in it?

I want to track a row selection in a table. So how can I create an event for that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your code inside the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method to track table row selection. Then you need to name category, action and label properly. I would recommend something like that:

```
NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section #%i", indexPath.section];
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker trackEventWithCategory:@"Table #1"
                                                 withAction:@"Select Row"
                                                  withLabel:label
                                                  withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
```

Actually, you can name category, action and label whatever you want. But it's better to give them convenient names, so it will be easier to find them in your statistics data.