# track event on the basis of selected row of the table through google analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I have been trying this code to track which row of the table is been selected using google analytics

```
NSString *label=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section#%i",indexPath.section];
    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker trackEventWithCategory:@"HOME"
                                                     withAction:@"Select Row"
                                                      withLabel:label
                                                      withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
```

But i always get the `error "No known instance method for selector trackEventWithCategory:withAction:withLabel:with Value:"`

Can anyone please guide me: I want to track which row of the table is selected so an event can be created using google analytics.

Comment: Your error saying that [GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker has no any method, name is `trackEventWithCategory:withAction:withLabel:with Value:`

Comment: It's nice have a another account like... http://stackoverflow.com/users/3513773/pooja and might be question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308547/how-to-track-event-of-row-selection-in-table-in-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got the solution

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
  [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"BUSINESS DETAILS "     
                                       action:@"Select Row"  // Event action (required)
                                       label:@"Selected"          // Event label
                                       value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]] build]];
```